# How to compare geolocations with different formats?

Tags: python, json, geolocation

I am using a JSON file of Amsterdam to get the coordinates of different areas and I want to compare these coordinates with a dataframe I produced with the columns latitude and longitude. However the formats are very different and I am not sure how to continue. This is the format of the JSON coordinates:

```
'area' : 'Noord'
'coordinates' :[[[4.971481, 52.325345],
      [4.971263, 52.32558],
      [4.971131, 52.325707],
      [4.970473, 52.326281],
      [4.970254, 52.326163],
      [4.969608, 52.326511],
      [4.96921, 52.326776],
      [4.967541, 52.327751]
```

and this is the format of my dataframe:

```
house_id      latitude      longitude
1             52.327751     4.967541
```

My expected output would be:

```
house_id      latitude      longitude       area
1             52.327751     4.967541       Noord
```

Basically, I want to compare the latitude and longitude columns of my df with the values of the JSON coordinates and if they are included in the JSON coordinates, write the area name to my df in the column "area". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your json is in a dict, you can just do a quick function:

```
def check(x):
    lat,lon = x['latitude'],x['longtiude']
    result = [True for coord in j['coordinates'][0] if [lon,lat] == coord]
    if result:
        return j['area']
    else:
        return None

df['area'] = df.apply(check,axis=1)
```

output:

```
   house_id   latitude  longtiude   area
0         1  52.327751   4.967541  Noord
```